# HTML5 skew just for bottom

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skew

I am creating a background and making it skew from the bottom only, but its also skewing from top:

I just want that top will remain straight only bottom will skew

Please make sure, I don't want to use absolute as i want to show content on top

The highlighted in the image should be straight one.

**CODE:**

```
#devheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 575px;  
    background: linear-gradient(150deg, #6840e6 43%, #5934b7 65%, #2c089c 85%);
    transform-origin: 0;
    -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -12deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -12deg);
    transform: skew(0deg, -12deg);
    top: 0;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    left: 0
}
```

please help:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do this, if you want one background for the entire thing, it's either skewed, or it's not skewed. You can always have a second element that's below the top one that's longer and skewed, to make it look like it's just one, or push the background up somehow maybe, so that the gap isn't visible

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @zack6849

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be difficult to achieve with gradients. I believe you'd be better of with images.

if gradients are not mandatory, you can go check out my codepen: https://codepen.io/johandegrieck-the-encoder/pen/YLOXga

```css
.supercontainer{
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  color:white;
}

.container{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  display:flex;
  z-index:0;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:flex-end;
}

.secondcontainer{
 transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  width:100%;
  height:350px;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:-150px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="supercontainer">
  
<div class="container">
  some content on top
</div>
<div class="secondcontainer">  
</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using multiple background to achieve this:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 background:
 linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 80%,#fff 80%),
 linear-gradient(150deg, #6840e6 43%, #5934b7 65%, #2c089c 85%);
}
```